# simple mesh warping without external library

Tags: mesh, interpolation, warp

i have to warp an image without external libraries (etc. opencv).

[Example](http://www11.pic-upload.de/01.10.14/3azb28hxna4f.png)

I also found a solution via google:

1. Iterate the pixel within the destination mesh
2. Calculate the relative mesh position of the pixel
3. Map the relative mesh position into the source mesh

How can i transform the position from the destination image into the source image?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a library like OpenCV, you will have to implement the geometric transforms yourself. The following slides are a good starting point.

http://engr.case.edu/merat_francis/eecs490f07/Lectures/Lecture4.pdf

You can also use OpenGL to do this. Again, you will be using interpolations that are available inside OpenGL libraries.